# Count number of items in a PHP array based on specific value

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [createdOn] => 2014-03-03 20:49:14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [createdOn] => 2014-05-06 08:29:47
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [createdOn] => 2014-05-07 10:37:56
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [createdOn] => 2014-06-01 09:11:58
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [createdOn] => 2014-06-01 12:29:16
        )

)
```

What I want to achieve however, is to count how many times a record appears in the array based on the month of the `createdOn` date. So something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        {
            [count] => 1
            [createdOn] => 'March'
        }

    [1] => Array
        {
            [count] => 2
            [createdOn] => 'May'
        }

    [2] => Array
        {
            [count] => 2
            [createdOn] => 'June'
        }
)
```

How can I get this result using PHP?

Comment: A basic `for` loop with the use of `strtotime()` should work. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you fetching this from a database? If so, use SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
$dates = array();
$dates[] = array('id' => 1, 'date' => '2014-03-01 12:29:16');
$dates[] = array('id' => 2, 'date' => '2014-03-01 12:29:16');
$dates[] = array('id' => 3, 'date' => '2014-04-01 12:29:16');
$dates[] = array('id' => 4, 'date' => '2014-05-01 12:29:16');
$dates[] = array('id' => 5, 'date' => '2014-06-01 12:29:16');
$dates[] = array('id' => 6, 'date' => '2014-06-01 12:29:16');

$counted = array();

array_walk_recursive($dates, function ($value, $key) use (& $counted) {
    if ($key == 'date') {
        $date = new DateTime($value);
        $monthName = $date->format('M');

        if (!isset($counted[$monthName])) {
            $counted[$monthName] = array('createdOn' => $monthName, 'count' => 0);
        }

        $counted[$monthName]['count']++;
    }
});

var_dump(array_values($counted));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have PHP do the heavy lifting for you, there's built-in functions for everything you would need. Using array_column() we can strip everything but the date keys, array_map() takes care of the proper formatting.

```
$dates = array(
  array('id' => 1, 'date' => '2014-03-01 12:29:16'),
  array('id' => 2, 'date' => '2014-03-01 12:29:16'),
  array('id' => 3, 'date' => '2014-04-01 12:29:16'),
  array('id' => 4, 'date' => '2014-05-01 12:29:16'),
  array('id' => 5, 'date' => '2014-06-01 12:29:16'),
  array('id' => 6, 'date' => '2014-06-01 12:29:16'),
);

$format = function ($ts) {
  return date_create($ts)->format('M');
};

$m = array_map($format, array_column($dates, 'date'));
```

Finally, array_count_values() gives us the tally.

```
array_count_values($m) =>

Array
(
  [Mar] => 2
  [Apr] => 1
  [May] => 1
  [Jun] => 2
)
```

Though if you get the data from a sql query, it's a better idea to just do your aggregation there instead.